# The page isn't redirecting properly in login filter

Tags: jsf, shiro

I want to implement this example https://github.com/hakdogan/ApacheShiro in my JSF 2.2 page.

I added into my login page `f:event`

```
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event type="javax.faces.event.PreRenderViewEvent" listener="#{loginController.authorizedUserControl}"/>
    </f:metadata>
    <h:head>
        ........
    </h:head>
```

**redirect method:**

```
public void authorizedUserControl(){

        if(null != SecurityUtils.getSubject().getPrincipal()){

            NavigationHandler nh =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
            nh.handleNavigation(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(), null, "/member/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true");

        }
    }
```

When I open the page I get:

```
The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.
```

How I can fix this?

**shiro.ini file**

```
[main]
authc.loginUrl = /authentication/login.xhtml
user.loginUrl = /authentication/login.xhtml

dataSource = org.apache.shiro.jndi.JndiObjectFactory
dataSource.resourceName = jdbc/DefaultDB
dataSource.resourceRef = true
jdbcRealm = com.crm.web.authentication.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $dataSource
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
securityManager.realm = $jdbcRealm
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.HashedCredentialsMatcher
credentialsMatcher.hashAlgorithmName = SHA-256
credentialsMatcher.storedCredentialsHexEncoded = true
credentialsMatcher.hashIterations = 5000
multipleroles = com.crm.web.authentication.MultipleRolesAuthorizationFilter
[users]
;admin = password

[urls]
/authentication/login.xhtml = authc
/authentication/passwordreset.xhtml = anon
/javax.faces.resource/** = anon
/** = authc
```

Comment: Check your shiro config

Comment: Did you **analyze/inspect/checked** your config? Did you check it the example works at all?

Comment: And did you see the login page is **protected** (needs authentication?) That is weird... but is is also in the example you based it on... So that is (imo) weird to...

Comment: hmmmm seems needed for form based authentication... Never used that, so forget my previous comment

Comment: When I delete all browser data it's working properly. In chrome I get ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after Tomcat reboot,